# Javascript Rails JSON Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a large json from my rails controller:

```
@json = {:Nodes => @nodes.as_json(:only => [:ID, :Lat, :Lon])}
```

and I want to use it in my javascript in my views. In a larger scope, I want to use the json to retrieve lat and lon's to plot on a Google Map. However, right now, I'm just trying to see if I can get all the points properly. My question is:

What's a good way to parse the json in the javascript file? (Note: the file's extension is still html.erb) I've tried:

```
var stuff = eval('(' + <%= @json %> + ')');
```

but that doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone help? Thanks so much!

Comment: I used firebug, and it says that there's an unexpected token of : but isn't that supposed to be a part of JSOn anyways?

Comment: Could you please post the relevant parts of your controller, html, and js files?

Comment: Sure Behrang! My controller function looks as follows: def map 
    @nodes = Node.all
    @json = {"Nodes" => @nodes.as_json(:only => [:ID, :Lat, :Lon])}
  end  and my html file simply looks like this: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var stuff = <%= @json %>;
var json = JSON.parse(stuff);
alert("text");
</script>
</body>
</html>    Any ideas? The Node class simply contains nodes with ID Lat and Lon along with other information that I don't include using the :include symbol

Comment: Could you edit your post to include your controller and view source? (by the by, I believe you can use back tick to `pre within a comment`)

Answer (score 1):

Since JSON is actually all legal javascript syntax, I frequently do this:

```
var stuff = <%= @json_hash.to_json %>;
```

Simplest thing that could possibly work. If you are getting your JSON from an untrusted source, it's better to use a library function to parse it, which will prevent it from executing code. Also, be sure to call `to_json` on your final hash. You don't want to just `to_s` it, which is the default in `erb`.

Comment: So I call the to_json method even though I called the as_json method in the controller? I tried that and it gave me an unexpected token { error. I'm so confused. If you could give me more help, that would be great!

Comment: I've also checked JSLint to make sure my JSON is valid and tried JSONParse ... what is wrong!?! =(

Comment: I believe `as_json` just returns a hash that is suitable for calling `to_json` on. You can try it in `rails console` to see what it's doing. I don't understand what you're saying about JSLint. If you have a valid JSON string, just drop it in the document after a `var` declaration.

Comment: Hi Austin, sorry about the confusion. I just rendered my json and put it into JSONlint which checks if its valid, and it checks out, so that's why I'm confused as to why it doesn't validly parse in the javascript. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post some representation of the JSON output, and the exact error message you are receiving?

Comment: Sure Austin, the json is rather long but I'll post as much of it as I can. It is: [{"node":{"ID":1301499692582,"Lat":42.3605063113369,"Lon":-71.0870862191138}},{"node":{"ID":1301499691515,"Lat":42.3605147089149,"Lon":-71.0870533282532}},{"node":{"ID":1301431075499,"Lat":42.3605456103,"Lon":-71.0875239075536}},{"node":{"ID":1301431074499,"Lat":42.3605594216623,"Lon":-71.0874833566893}} etc. Any ideas on what may be wrong? I'm getting an Unexpected Syntax error {  =(

Comment: Wait. So I see in another comment that you are calling `JSON.parse` in javascript. If that is the case, you are going to need to quote and escape it in the output. My idea was just to let the browser parse it at load time, in which case you wouldn't need `JSON.parse` at all. If you want to do it that way, you could do `hash.to_json.to_json` to double escape everything.

Comment: Hi Austin, first I'd like to say thank you so much for trying to help me out. To reduce confusion, in my controller I am calling as_json on my object and setting that to the @json variable. Now in my view I'm doing <%= @json.to_json.to_json %> but javascript is throwing me a unexpected syntax error & ... I'm guessing its coming from this: var stuff = &quot;[{\&quot;node\&quot;:{\&quot;ID\&quot;:1301499692582,\&quot;Lat\&quot;:42.3605063113369,\&quot;Lon\&quot;:-71.0870862191138}} which was taken from the page source. Any ideas on this error and why I'm getting "&quot" all the time?

Comment: Hmm. I was expecting it to escape the quotes with `\"` rather than `&quot;`. I'd say calling `to_json` twice is a bad idea. Does it work if you just write something like `var data = <%= {:test => 'hash'}.to_json %>;`? It seems like there's something I'm missing about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
@json = {:Nodes => @nodes.map({|n| [n[:ID], n[:Lat], n[:Lon]] })}.to_json
```

using prototype you could do this:

```
var stuff = '<%= raw @json %>'.evalJSON();
```

or using jquery:

```
var stuff = jQuery.parseJSON('<%= raw @json %>');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4 all this solutions not work for me, so i make this:

```
var consumers;
consumers = <%= @consumers.to_json.html_safe %>;
```

So `consumers[0]` generate  `Object`(model Rails), you can iterate to transform in your objects like:

```
function consumersRubyToJavascriptArray(json){
    for (var i = 0; i< json.length; i++) {
        consumers.push(new Consumer({ id: json[i][0], name: json[i][2], phone: json[i][3], cpf: json[i][4]}));
    }
}
```